# Crawling a second page answer; curl

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm crawling a few websites, everything it's working fine,

but .... I have one specific website that I'm trying to crawl,
and it's making a few "redirects" before landing to the web I want.

So it's something like ...

http://www.example.com/?day=01/01/2016&action=search_prices

this will go to http://www.example.com/search/default.aspx take a few seconds to search the answer page and then show it on there.

Is there any way to easily do this? any hint, clue, etc would be awesome

Simple code right now (almost all the sites I was crawling were jsons):

```
function get_web_page( $url ){
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect

            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('HeaderName: HeaderValue'),

            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
        );

        $ch      = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $content = curl_exec( $ch );
        $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
        $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
        $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );

        $header['errno']   = $err;
        $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
        $header['content'] = $content;
        return $header;
}
```

Comment: What kind of redirect is the page doing? If it's an HTTP redirect then curl should follow it, but if it's <meta> or JavaScript or something else then you'll need something else, like a headless browser, or perhaps parsing the response and scraping the second page yourself.

Comment: Hi @MattParlane it's http but when require for the result with curl because of the time it takes it's giving me an empty response

Comment: @MattParlane the link is something like this but it's like this one https://www.priceline.com/fly/#/search/JFK:LGA:EWR-MIA-20150923/MIA-JFK:LGA:EWR-20150930/1?input-arm-key=3F4A050A3E4B050Akc6yntBrxkmxC75zatmtSA2607&depart-time-filter-start1=2015-09-23T05:40&depart-time-filter-end1=2015-09-23T20:00&direction=outbound&slice1-alts=SWF:HPN:ISP-FLL:PBI&slice2-alts=FLL:PBI-SWF:HPN:ISP&country-code=US&v=ALLOW

Comment: It's actually not an HTTP redirect, you can see that in (for example) Chrome's network inspector. It's all done in one page load, with JavaScript handling replacing the page HTML. I don't think curl will help, you need a headless browser, or you could try dissecting with the JS is doing and calling the same Ajax endpoints (probably complicated).